# форматирование текста (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

здравствуйте, в функцию поступает такой текст:

```
hello world, this is message, welcome to <a href="site.ru">site.ru</a> we are bla bla bla. <br><br class="br"> good bye!
```

как сделать из такого текста такой (затем вернув):

```
    hello world, this is message, welcome to site.ru we are bla bla bla.

 good bye!
```

то есть от ссылки мы обрезаем html код, оставляя только сам текст ссылки, а `<br и <br class="br"> заменяем на перенос строки \n`

спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```js
const text = 'hello world, this is message, welcome to <a href="site.ru">site.ru</a> we are bla bla bla. <br><br class="br"> good bye!';
const s = document.createElement('span');
s.innerHTML = text;
console.log(s.innerText);
```

Comment: как я понял ваш вариант полностью форматирует HTML тэги? а можно сделать что то похожее, только чтобы затрагивались ссылки и br которые приведены в вопросе